# Updating all entries URIs after changing entry URL format

Tags: url, sections

After publishing some entries, I've changed the section setting "Entry URL Format" from news/{slug} to news/{id} but I had to re-save every entry to reflect the change.
Is there a better and fast way to update all entries URIs after changing the entry URL format?

Comment: Normally a background-task should take care of it, as soon as you save the section setting.

Comment: @VictorIn unfortunately, that's not the case here.

Comment: Odd, try sending a support-request from your dashboard including the runtime folder to P&T. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Does clearing the caches help?

Comment: @SimonKuran clearing caches and re-saving section settings does not help. I've sent a support request as it might be a bug.

Comment: is there any update on this?

Comment: @BenCroker A support request was sent to Pixel&Tonic and I think they're working on it. I'll update this question once I get a solution from them.

Comment: @BenCroker as the latest response from Brandon, it was an issue with Craft, and fixed for next release. I'll add a detailed answer once the fix is released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entries won't immediately get updated, as it could take a little while to go through all of them, but you should see a little progress bar in your CP header immediately after updating your section's settings, and if you click on it, it will give you more details -- saying that a "Resave Elements" background task is running. Once that has completed, your entries will have new URLs.

In my case, it was not working as indented with localised entries but thankfully that was fixed on build 2562.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering what's going on with a background update, look at the database, there's a table called `tasks`, and each row has a `steps` counter to tell you how many records are left to update. You can refresh the table to see how the updates are progressing.